# Tricky Javascript regex replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm coding a custom markdown parser that should preprocess user input so that each line of the input that starts with three ticks should have the reference code trimmed and all it's spaces replaced with underscores. So in this fiddle

````js
var e = document.getElementById("thetext");
var feedback = document.getElementById("feedback");

var sorted = function(haystack) {
  var re = /$```\s*(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)\s*$/g;
  return haystack.replace(re, '```$1_$3');
};

e.addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
  feedback.innerHTML = sorted(e.value);
}, true);
````

```css
textarea { width: 400px; height: 400px;}
```

````html
<textarea id="thetext">
A custom block code marker with reference:

``` John 3:16
For God so loved the world 
``` 

another one with two spaces to be replaced:

```1 Cor 2:15-45 
Some other marked up text followed by white space 
```

</textarea>
<pre id="feedback">Tab out to see result</pre>
````

the output should be exactly like the input except for these two lines:

````
```John_3:16
````

and

````
```1_Cor_2:15-45
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky replacements are done easiest with a callback function.

````js
var thetext = document.getElementById("thetext");
var feedback = document.getElementById("feedback");

var sorted = function(haystack) {
  var re = /^```(.*)/gm;
  return haystack.replace(re, function ($0, $1) {
      return '```' + $1.trim().replace(/\s/g, '_');
  });
};

thetext.addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
  feedback.textContent = sorted(this.value);
});
````

```css
textarea { width: 400px; height: 400px;}
```

````html
<textarea id="thetext">
A custom block code marker with reference:

``` John 3:16
For God so loved the world 
``` 

another one with two spaces to be replaced:

```1 Cor 2:15-45 
Some other marked up text followed by white space 
```

</textarea>
<pre id="feedback">Tab out to see result</pre>
````

Comment: `$1.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '_')` **==>** `$1.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '_');`

Comment: @Tushar Nice. Apparently I'm too old-school for that.

Comment: Wow! didn't know you can use a callback. Thanks for the great introduction.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex should be multiline .
The ^ and $ anchors now match at the beginning/end of each line respectively, instead of beginning/end of the entire string.

````
/^```\s*(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)\s*$/gm;
````